# Why does the Smooth Brush behave differently when using it via Slide Relax?

Tags: edit-mode, sculpting, topology, retopology

It turns out that the smooth brush behaves differently depending on which brush you activated the smooth on (pressing Shift)? Where does the manual tell you how it works?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smoothing mode for that brush relaxes the underlying topology, evening out the distance between vertices.

Here's the manual description:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/sculpting/tools/slide_relax.html

Here's video demonstrations from the developer:

https://developer.blender.org/D6059